# Sending Two Mails At a time in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I need to send two mails one to client and one to admin in asp.net
Below is the code i used but it didn't send two mails , it just sent mail to client only 
I had made two functions one for admin one for client but it doesn't work.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace Mail
{
    public partial class Mail : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public void admin()
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
                // Sender e-mail address.
                Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);
                // Recipient e-mail address.
                Msg.To.Add("email@gmail.com");
                Msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
                Msg.Body = "UserName " + txtName.Text + " UserEmail " + txtEmail.Text + "</br>";
                // your remote SMTP server IP.
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password");
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(Msg);
                //Msg = null;
                lbltxt.Text = "Thanks for Contact us";
                // Clear the textbox valuess
                txtName.Text = "";
                txtSubject.Text = "";
                txtMessage.Text = "";
                txtEmail.Text = "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
            }
        }
        public void client()
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
                // Sender e-mail address.
                Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);
                // Recipient e-mail address.
                Msg.To.Add(txtEmail.Text);
                Msg.Subject = "Thanks you for downloading our product";
                Msg.Body = "we loves your privacy , this product is in BETA Mode , Do Feedback us about this Product   http://www.google.com    >";
                // your remote SMTP server IP.
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password");
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(Msg);
                //Msg = null;
                lbltxt.Text = "Thanks for Contact us";
                // Clear the textbox valuess
                txtName.Text = "";
                txtSubject.Text = "";
                txtMessage.Text = "";
                txtEmail.Text = "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
            }
        }
        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            admin();
            client();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the email addresses correct? Are they routable by gmail?

Comment: Yes emails are correct for security reasons i did not show real email addresses

Comment: Adil - SO is not for us to do your debugging please show what you've tried

Comment: @TobyAllen no, of course I had forgotten the word "question" after it. Btw, at 6k you should know what a diamond means (_that_ would be the major problem, not my rep!). And, "you're" not "your".

Comment: The `Msg.From` field should be initialized with *your* email address, not the email address of the client.  Gmail should refuse to accept messages with spoofed `From` addresses like that.